# (When not assuming differentiability) what is the definition of Fisher information?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, definition, fisher-information

Here we assume (for simplicity) that the parameter $\theta$ is one-dimensional.

When one has sufficient regularity and can push in partial derivatives to and pull out partial derivatives from the integral sign, then all of the following definitions are equivalent:

Define the score $S$ to be the partial derivative with respect to the parameter $\theta$  ( i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\ell$ ) of the log-likelihood $\ell = \log p_{\theta}$. Then one sees the following three definitions for the Fisher information $I(\theta)$:

(1) $I(\theta) = Var_{\theta}(S)$

(2) $I(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_{\theta}(S^2)$

(3) $I(\theta) = -\mathbb{E}_{\theta}\left[ \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} S \right]$

If I remember correctly, the equivalence of (1) and (2) requires a partial derivative to be exchanged around an integral sign once, while the equivalence of (2) and (3) requires a partial derivative to be exchanged around an integral sign yet another time.

**Question:** Which is the correct definition of $I(\theta)$ without *any* differentiability assumptions?

Comment: *"without any differentiability assumptions"* I wonder about a practical example that can help this question become more intuitive.

Comment: *"without any differentiability assumptions"* What do you mean by this? What assumptions? Do you mean when the score is not existing, or when the derivative of the score is not existing?